# Sort Date "yyyy-mm-dd" in JSON using python

Tags: python, json

I have a question about data sorting in JSON using python. This is the data I have:

```
{
    "DE":[{
            "Date": "2020-01-18",
            "Confirmed Cases": 50,
            "Predicted Cases": 0
        },
        {
            "Date": "2020-01-15",
            "Confirmed Cases": 4,
            "Predicted Cases": 13
        },
       {
            "Date": "2020-01-17",
            "Confirmed Cases": 50,
            "Predicted Cases": 0
        },
        {
            "Date": "2020-01-13",
            "Confirmed Cases": 4,
            "Predicted Cases": 13
        },
       ...],

     "AL":[{
            "Date": "2020-01-18",
            "Confirmed Cases": 50,
            "Predicted Cases": 0
        },
        {
            "Date": "2020-01-15",
            "Confirmed Cases": 4,
            "Predicted Cases": 13
        },
       {
            "Date": "2020-01-17",
            "Confirmed Cases": 50,
            "Predicted Cases": 0
        },
        {
            "Date": "2020-01-13",
            "Confirmed Cases": 4,
            "Predicted Cases": 13
            ....
        }],
         ....
}
```

`"DE` and `"AL"` are the name of the states and there are 50 of them. Inside each state, there is  a big list holding data in the form of dictionaries of each individual day. My question is how can I sort the `"Date"` in this case, so that it can change to :

```
{
    "DE":[{
            "Date": "2020-01-13",
            "Confirmed Cases": 4,
            "Predicted Cases": 13
        }, 
         {
            "Date": "2020-01-15",
            "Confirmed Cases": 4,
            "Predicted Cases": 13
        },
         {
            "Date": "2020-01-17",
            "Confirmed Cases": 50,
            "Predicted Cases": 0
        },
         {
            "Date": "2020-01-18",
            "Confirmed Cases": 50,
            "Predicted Cases": 0
        },
       ...],

     "AL":[{
            "Date": "2020-01-13",
            "Confirmed Cases": 4,
            "Predicted Cases": 13
        }, 
         {
            "Date": "2020-01-15",
            "Confirmed Cases": 4,
            "Predicted Cases": 13
        },
         {
            "Date": "2020-01-17",
            "Confirmed Cases": 50,
            "Predicted Cases": 0
        },
         {
            "Date": "2020-01-18",
            "Confirmed Cases": 50,
            "Predicted Cases": 0
        }
        ...
             ],
         ....
}
```

I am new to python and data processing. I've thought of a number of methods but all of them have different flaws. Therefore, can you guys help me? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a simple `for` loop and the `sort` function. In your case you can loop over all entries in you dictionary and call sort on them as `sort` will run in-place. The sort works via a custom key function, which uses the `Date` entry as key for the sort.

If you would like to reverse the order during the sort you can set `reverse=True` in the `sort` call.

```py
for _, entries in data.items():
    entries.sort(key=lambda entry: entry['Date'])
```

**Result:**

```py
{
 'DE': [
  {'Date': '2020-01-13', 'Confirmed Cases': 4, 'Predicted Cases': 13},
  {'Date': '2020-01-15', 'Confirmed Cases': 4, 'Predicted Cases': 13},
  {'Date': '2020-01-17', 'Confirmed Cases': 50, 'Predicted Cases': 0},
  {'Date': '2020-01-18', 'Confirmed Cases': 50, 'Predicted Cases': 0}
 ],
 'AL': [
  {'Date': '2020-01-13', 'Confirmed Cases': 4, 'Predicted Cases': 13},
  {'Date': '2020-01-15', 'Confirmed Cases': 4, 'Predicted Cases': 13},
  {'Date': '2020-01-17', 'Confirmed Cases': 50, 'Predicted Cases': 0},
  {'Date': '2020-01-18', 'Confirmed Cases': 50, 'Predicted Cases': 0}
 ]}
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much. What does the underline represent in this case in the loop.? Does the "data.item" represent the json?

Comment: The `_` basically means you don't need to save the first variable of the tuple. I was asumed that `data` would be your dictionary/json and `items()` is an iterator over each entry in the dictionary, which always returns The key and the value.

Comment: @FrankLiu I hope this answers all your questions.

Comment: Cool, let's me try it and get back to you. But really helpful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort right dates like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
json_list = {
"DE":[{
        "Date": "2020-01-18",
        "Confirmed Cases": 50,
        "Predicted Cases": 0
    },
    {
        "Date": "2020-01-15",
        "Confirmed Cases": 4,
        "Predicted Cases": 13
    },
   {
        "Date": "2020-01-17",
        "Confirmed Cases": 50,
        "Predicted Cases": 0
    },
    {
        "Date": "2020-01-13",
        "Confirmed Cases": 4,
        "Predicted Cases": 13
    },
   ...],

 "AL":[{
        "Date": "2020-01-18",
        "Confirmed Cases": 50,
        "Predicted Cases": 0
    },
    {
        "Date": "2020-01-15",
        "Confirmed Cases": 4,
        "Predicted Cases": 13
    },
   {
        "Date": "2020-01-17",
        "Confirmed Cases": 50,
        "Predicted Cases": 0
    },
    {
        "Date": "2020-01-13",
        "Confirmed Cases": 4,
        "Predicted Cases": 13
        ....
    }],
     ....
}

sorted_DE = sorted(json_list['DE'], key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d'))
sorted_AL = sorted(json_list['AL'], key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d'))
sorted_date={"DE": sorted_DE, "AL": sorted_AL}

print(sorted_date)
```